# how to fix this if_else statement

Tags: r, dplyr

does anyone know how I can correct this if_else statement?

```r
 dplyr::mutate(`Possible Hospital Placement` = 
               if_else(`resource_id` %in% c('123', '234', '456', '678', '789') |
                       `resource_name` %in% c("Hospital"), "Yes", "NA")) %>%
```

Basically idea is to search the dataframe for all those possible resource_ids or if there are any records with the word "hospital" in the resource_name then I want the column "possible hospital placement" to say yes otherwise NA

I am trying to fix this statement but for some reason the code is not giving me any records of hospitals. I am only able to get the records which has the listed resour_ids

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: The code seems to be fine except that you don't need quotes around `NA` i.e. `NA_character_`.  Can you show the `dput` of a small example that shows the issue

Comment: It may be also that there are some leading/lagging spaces in the column.  Can you try by using `trimws` to remove those.  Without an example, these are just guesses

Comment: The code above is true when resource_name is equal to "Hospital" if you want resource_name to contain the word "Hospital" then you need to use a regular expression .  See the `grep` function as a starting point.

Comment: If Hospital is a vector or another actual object, you should not use quotes, as in Hospital, not "Hospital". Otherwise, if you want 'resource_name' to contain 'Hospital', you should use regex

Comment: I agree with @Dave2e. `%in%` is for *set membership*, so `'123' %in% c('123','234')` is true but `'123' %in% c('12345678','234')` is false, as is `'hospital' %in% 'possible hospital placement'`. I think you need `\`resource_id\` %in% c(...) | grepl('hospital', \`resource_name\`, ignore.case=TRUE)`.